# Storing sorting terms in URL so can be bookmarked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

I am currently creating a simple single page application where you can sort entries by name and so on. What I am looking to accomplish is a way to store the current sort chosen (but not a different web page, something similar to a PHP Get). I am not very confident or familiar with Javascript, AJAX and so on because of this I do not know how to store and read from a URL in JS.

Comment: You mean save sorting terms in a querystring right ? What kind of language are you using ? PHP ? ASP ?

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly accomplished by using the `#fragment` part of the URL.  Browsers will not reload a page if only the fragment is changed.  For example, changing the location from:

```
http://example.com/my-single-page-app#by-name
```

to

```
http://example.com/my-single-page-app#by-date
```

Will not reload the page, and JS can be used to update the actual display (this is a single page app after all).

(Of course, you can store much more than that in the `#fragment`)